# What is the modern objective c syntax for NSUserDefault setObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax

I just showed my colleague my code and he reminded me to use modern objective c syntax. I felt like an idiot because I had no idea what he meant. How can I convert:

```
NSUserDefaults *rankDate = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[rankDate setObject:self.date forKey:@"rankDate"];
[rankDate setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.date.people] forKey:@"people"];
[rankDate synchronize];
```

into "modern objective c syntax"?

I've been doing this for years and never heard of this syntax. Should I be worried?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure he isn't calling "Swift" the "new Objective C"? Swift is technically the successor to ObjC, but it's still a new language.

Comment: I initially had [NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.date.people] and he changed it to @(self.date.people). So I'm pretty sure he meant objective c. I'm not sure how I can change 'setObject' though.

Comment: @Arc676 - I'll agree on you with this. But the term [Modern Objective-c syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html) exists. I curious if there's something.

Comment: @EricChuang In that case you should have posted that in your question, not the thing he added.

Comment: I don't understand why my question got down voted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it came up in comments, I thought I'd go ahead and elevate it to an answer so it doesn't get lost. The better code here would be:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setObject:self.date forKey:@"rankDate"];
[ud setInteger:self.date.people forKey:@"people"];
```

I've made several changes. First, `rankDate` makes no sense as the name of `standardUserDefaults` and is very misleading. Second, it uses `setInteger:forKey:` rather than messing around with `NSNumber` wrappers. There's no need for that. Finally, it gets rid of `synchronize`. That seldom does what you really meant, especially on iOS ([it just waits](https://twitter.com/Catfish_Man/status/674727133017587712)).

That said, this whole object model is incredibly confusing. It seems "date" isn't a date, "people" isn't people, and you're saving the same data twice. But that's a separate issue. The main thing is that there's no proper application of "modern Objective-C" here. You shouldn't be using `NSNumber` (i.e. `@(...)`), and there's no subscripting on `NSUserDefaults` (i.e. `ud[@"..."]`).

(The existence of `setInteger:forKey:` and all the other specific `set` methods on `NSUserDefaults` I believe explains why it does not have subscripting. That would special-case objects, which would make the code inconsistent and encourage `NSNumber` wrapping when it isn't needed.)

Answer (score 3):

Using subscripting, so a statement like `[dictionary setObject:@3 forKey:key]` becomes `dictionary[key] = @3`.

I found it at the bottom of the apple document about ["Adopting Modern Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW13).

P.S. seems NSUserDefaults does not support the subscripting syntax, i found a github project which allows this:
https://gist.github.com/tonyarnold/3196558

Comment: Does this work with NSUserDefaults though? I tried rankDate[@"rankDate"] = self.date and it didn't work. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: I think your syntax is correct. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: In order to use the new subscripting syntax, the object needs to implement `objectForKeyedSubscript` and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`. As you note, `NSUserDefaults` does not (not completely certain why it doesn't, but it doesn't.)

Comment: @RobNapier so to clarify, the x[@"y"] = self.object syntax only works with NSDictionary and not NSUserDefaults? Also, there is no other way of setting values in NSUserDefaults except using setObjectForKey method?

Comment: the `x[@"y"]` syntax works with anything that implements the `KeyedSubscript` methods (that's more than `NSDictionary`, but doesn't include `NSUserDefaults`). I don't quite know what you mean by "no other way." There are lots of clever ways I could devise. But none are as consistent as `setObjectForKey:`. Now that I've thought about it, I see why they didn't make it subscripted. You can store lots of non-object things in NSUserDefaults (`setBool:forKey:`, etc.) Wrapping just `setObject:forKey:` without all the others would be inconsistent. You should just use `setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: In fact, in this case you shouldn't even be using `setObject:forKey:` or `NSNumber` anyway. You should just use `setInteger:forKey:`. That would get rid of all the extra wrapping and unwrapping.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you originally had

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:self.date.people]
```

and your colleague changed it to

```
@(self.date.people)
```

This is because the `@()` syntax is shorthand for converting a non-Objective-C expression to an `NSNumber`.

For example, `5` is an `int`. This is not an Objective-C type, i.e. it cannot be casted to `id`. So if you need to convert it to `id`, what you (using "old ObjC") would be `[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]`. However, this is long and tedious so what you do is `@5`, which would be the "new ObjC".

From the [page that @the_UB linked to](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html):

> ...this converter recommends additional changes to your code, including:...
>   • Converting to literals, so a statement like `[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]` becomes `@3`.
>   • Using subscripting, so a statement like `[dictionary setObject:@3 forKey:key]` becomes `dictionary[key] = @3`